# Understanding tensor fields in coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

A tensor field of type $(r,s)$ on a smooth manifold $M^{n}$ is a map
$$
t\colon M \to \bigsqcup_{p\in M} (T_{p}M)^r_s
$$
where $$(T_{p}M)^r_s = \underbrace{T_{p}M\otimes \cdots \otimes T_{p}M}_{r}\otimes \underbrace{T_{p}M^{\ast} \otimes \cdots \otimes T_{p}M^{\ast}}_{s}$$
By fixing a smooth chart $(U, x^{1},\dots,x^{n})$ about $p\in M$ we obtain an expression for $t_p$ in terms of the basis of the tensor product:
$$
t_{p} = \sum_{\substack{i_{1},\dots ,i_{r} \\ j_{1},\dots ,j_{s}}} \zeta_{j_{1}\dots j_{s}}^{i_{1}\dots i_{r}}(p) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i_{1}}} \otimes \cdots \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i_{r}}} \otimes dx^{j_{1}} \otimes \cdots \otimes dx^{j_{s}}
$$
In the book I am following, Elon Lima's tensor calculus, he goes further and states that
$$
t_{p}= \sum_{\substack{i_{1}<\cdots <i_{r} \\ j_{1}<\cdots < j_{s}}} \zeta_{j_{1}\dots j_{s}}^{i_{1}\dots i_{r}}(p) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i_{1}}} \otimes \cdots \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i_{r}}} \otimes dx^{j_{1}} \otimes \cdots \otimes dx^{j_{s}}
$$
Why the sum is under that constraint? Why if any index is repeated it give zero? I understand that in the case of differential forms this happens with the wedge product, but I don't quite see why it happens in the tensor product. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you sure there is no further assumption on $t$? What is this book? As it stands, it is false to me. For instance, $dx^1\otimes dx^2 + dx^2\otimes dx^1$ is a tensor which cannot be written as in your last expression

Comment: @Didier No, there are no more assumptions. The book is called "Cálculo tensorial" by Elon Lima, section 4.4 "Campos de tensores sobre variedades" (https://impa.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/PM_33.pdf)

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Portuguese, but the words in this paragraph are close enough to French for me to say that it should definitely be a typo: maybe the author had in mind differential forms when writing this. This might even be a copy-paste error: the author could have already written the case with differential forms, had replaced all $\wedge$ by $\otimes$ but forgot about the indexes under the sum

Comment: @Didier Okay, so in general only the first expression is true. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula in Lima's book is wrong. This becomes very clear if you look at p. 73:

[image]

This corresponds to the first formula in your question. We cannot omit any tupel $(i_1,\ldots,i_r,j_1,\ldots,j_s) \in \{1,\ldots,n\}^{r+s}$ (as it is done in Lima's formula). If it were correct to consider only tuples such that
$$i_1 < \ldots < i_r \text{ and } j_1 < \ldots < j_r \phantom{x},\tag{*}$$
we would get a basis for $(T_pM)^r_s$ having less than $N = n^{r+s}$ elements though $N$ is the dimension of $(T_pM)^r_s$.

And, by the way, if $r > n$ or $s > n$, then there *does not exist any* tuple such that $i_1 < \ldots < i_r$ and  $j_1 < \ldots < j_r$ satisfying (*) since all $i_k, j_l \le n$.